# PycURL unsetopt for WRITEFUNCTION

Tags: python-3.x, pycurl

I'm using PycURL to send multiple request to a specific API, before my service is running I'm sending a dummy request using `PycURL.perform()`

To avoid printing into the console I'm using

`PycURL.setopt(PycURL.WRITEFUNCTION, noop_write_function)`

Now after I get a response I need I want to avoid the write function overhead so I'm trying to use `unsetopt()` but it doesn't seems to work.

Whats the good practice to restore the null value to the WRITEFUNCTION?

Part of the script:

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://someurl.com')

# send demo http request to open connection with keep alive flag
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, noop_write_function)
c.perform()

# actually writing data to bytesIO
buffer = BytesIO()
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
```

Thanks,
Hod

Answer (score 0):

`WRITEDATA` and `WRITEFUNCTION` cover the same functionality. Note also that depending on Python version and type of argument given to `WRITEDATA`, `WRITEDATA` may be converted to a `WRITEFUNCTION` call.

You could try unsetting both `WRITEFUNCTION` and `WRITEDATA`.